# Update post title from external file?

Tags: php, posts, wp-update-post

I have an external script I wrote (for admins only) that loads in the following at the top:

```
require_once('./../wp-blog-header.php');
```

I'm aware that it can be a plugin, but it's just not right now.. it's just a standard php script.

Inside this script I have a form where it allows the person viewing to update a title.

Here is my code when they submit the form:

```
$post_data = array(
  'ID'         => $_POST['post_id'],
  'post_title' => $_POST['post_title']
);
wp_update_post($post_data);
```

wp_update_post() actually returns an ID, which makes me think its working, but the post simply doesn't change, and the title never updates.

What might I be missing here? At the very least I would expect an error if it doesn't work.

I'm positive the ID and the Title are correct/filled in.

Comment: Are you updating revision IDs, perhaps?

Comment: I'm finding the ID by using `$post->ID`. Would that always return the actual post, or could that return revision IDs?

Comment: Your code is very out of context. I can't say what is happening really.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I use this code when I want to run WordPress externally.

update.php

```
function find_wordpress_base_path() {
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    do {
        //it is possible to check for other files here
        if( file_exists($dir."/wp-config.php") ) {
            return $dir;
        }
    } while( $dir = realpath("$dir/..") );
    return null;
}

define( 'BASE_PATH', find_wordpress_base_path()."/" );
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require(BASE_PATH . 'wp-load.php');

$post_id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

// Update post
$my_post = array(
    'ID'           => $post_id,
    'post_title'   => $title, // new title
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to update the title.As the frist step include the database files.

```
require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
```

Then use the following code to udpate wordpress title.

```
 $updatePost = array(   
        'ID' => $postCSVContent[0], // wordpress Id
        'post_title'    => $postCSVContent['1'], // Updated title
        'post_content'  => $postCSVContent['2'], // Updated content
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1
    );

    wp_update_post( $updatePost );
```

Please also refer the tutorial that explain how to read data from CSV and udpate the post externally.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/code-snippets/insert-update-wordpress-post-programmatically/